# My geom cannot transform

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a query like this:

```
WITH var AS (
    SELECT
        '' AS periode, 
        '' AS group,
        '' AS facility_name,
        '' AS country
)
SELECT
    row_number() OVER () AS gid,
    ST_Transform (ST_Segmentize (ST_MakeLine (ST_Transform (a.geom, 953027), ST_Transform (b.geom, 953027)), 100000), 4326) geom
FROM
    tbl_ttms a,
    tbl_ttps b,
    var
WHERE
    a.id_ttp = b.id
  AND
    CASE WHEN var.periode != '' THEN a.periode = ''
         ELSE a.periode = a.periode
    END
  AND 
    CASE WHEN var.group != '' THEN a.group = '' 
         ELSE a.group = a.group
    END
  AND
    CASE WHEN var.facility_name != '' THEN a.faclity_name = ''
         ELSE a.faclity_name = a.faclity_name
    END
  AND
    CASE WHEN var.country != '' THEN a.country = ''
         ELSE a.country = a.country
    END
```

And the error is:

```
ERROR:  could not form projection (PJ) from 'srid=4326' to 'srid=953027'
```

My PostGIS version is 3.1 and my PostgreSQL version is 13. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Coordinate system "953027" is unknown to PostGIS. Can you give details about that crs?

Comment: You seem to be doing assignment in CASE statements in the WHERE clause of a SELECT statement. Even if it were legal, it seems exceptionally bad practice.

Comment: @Vince actually it's legal. Usage should be restricted to cases where the conditional is known at planning time (e.g. within a `FORMAT`) to be _somewhat_ practicable, though...(maybe its comparing *constants* that is legal  while dynamic assignment is not?)

Comment: Seems to be due to https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/53027/. The dirty solution is executing SQL from https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/53027/postgis/ Maybe there is a better solution but I don't know if any equivalent of this particular SRS code in default EPSG database.

Comment: When I run the query in my local postgresql, it runs normally after adding spatial_ref_sys with the same postgis and postgresql versions as on the server. But when I run the query on the server there is an error like my question above.

Comment: @geozealot I guess my issue with the CASEs is that the `var` fields are always empty strings, so the first WHEN is never true, so each ELSE evaluates to `a.field = a.field` which is always true, so the WHERE is `a.id_ttp = b.id
  AND true AND true AND true AND true` -- it's all just a waste of bits -- *and* that means the CTE isn't necessary ***and*** all this noise masks the lack of a proper JOIN. This code could be written in three lines.

Comment: Forget about where statements in queries. If I omit the with and where and just use select ST_Transform (ST_Segmentize (ST_MakeLine (ST_Transform (a.geom, 953027), ST_Transform (b.geom, 953027)), 100000), 4326) the geom will show an error like this: ERROR: could not form projection (PJ) from 'srid=4326' to 'srid=953027' I've added spatial_ref_sys 953027

Comment: Similar question: [PostGIS ST_Transform() fails for many srid on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/396058/10588)

Comment: Yes its similiar thanx! and the next question how can i downgrade gdal-3.1.2 to gdal-3.0.4 on ubuntu 20.04?